# article when talking in general

Tags: articles

> At the age of six the author visited **a** theater for the first time.

Is the use of "**a**" correct,
if he had never visited any theater before that time?

Comment: Yes, it is correct (general vs. specific articles), if the context does not provide any SPECIFIC theatre (i.e., the context on a specific theatre's not established/identified, but there exist that specific theatre). Use 'the' otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between articles in this case and the choice of the right one depends on whether "theater" (or "theatre") meant is the **form of art** or a **location** where such form of art is practiced.

For the location, you can use '*a*' because likely no particular location is meant.  For the form of art, you're likely to use "the" (similar to "*the opera*" or "*the cinema*").

Answer (score 1):

As a *building* **theatre** is countable  but as *plays* it is uncountable

> I enjoy theatre and swimming.

The verb is **visited** then it means a building, but **visited a theater** idiomatically means **watched theatre**, then it implies

> At the age of six the author watched theater for the first time.